# Memory leak when using DnsGetCacheDataTable

Tags: c, windows, memory-leaks, dns

The following code shows cached domain names in DNS client. Could somebody please help me to find the memory leak when it hits  ***int stat = DnsGetCacheDataTable(pEntry);*** line?
PS: please use DNSAPI.lib while compiling the code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <WinDNS.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
typedef struct _DNS_CACHE_ENTRY {
    struct _DNS_CACHE_ENTRY* pNext; // Pointer to next entry
    PWSTR pszName; // DNS Record Name
    unsigned short wType; // DNS Record Type
    unsigned short wDataLength; // Not referenced
    unsigned long dwFlags; // DNS Record FlagsB
} DNSCACHEENTRY, *PDNSCACHEENTRY;

typedef int(WINAPI *DNS_GET_CACHE_DATA_TABLE)(PDNSCACHEENTRY);
void UpdateDNS(void)
{

    PDNSCACHEENTRY pEntry = (PDNSCACHEENTRY) malloc(sizeof(DNSCACHEENTRY));
    // Loading DLL
    HINSTANCE hLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("DNSAPI.dll"));
    // Get function address
    DNS_GET_CACHE_DATA_TABLE DnsGetCacheDataTable = (DNS_GET_CACHE_DATA_TABLE) GetProcAddress(hLib, "DnsGetCacheDataTable");
    int stat = DnsGetCacheDataTable(pEntry);
    printf("stat = %d\n", stat);
    pEntry = pEntry->pNext;
    while (pEntry) {
        wprintf(L"%s : %d \n", (pEntry->pszName), (pEntry->wType));
        pEntry = pEntry->pNext;
    }
    free(pEntry);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    while (TRUE)
    {
        Sleep(100);
        UpdateDNS();
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried with Deleaker because at the first glance the code looked well: [image: leaks]

Then started debugging... and of course! You free not original pEntry but modified one.

Here the corrected code:

```
void UpdateDNS(void)
{

    PDNSCACHEENTRY pEntry = (PDNSCACHEENTRY) malloc(sizeof(DNSCACHEENTRY) + 0x10000);
    PDNSCACHEENTRY pFirstEntry = pEntry;
    // Loading DLL
    HINSTANCE hLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("DNSAPI.dll"));
    // Get function address
    DNS_GET_CACHE_DATA_TABLE DnsGetCacheDataTable = (DNS_GET_CACHE_DATA_TABLE) GetProcAddress(hLib, "DnsGetCacheDataTable");
    int stat = DnsGetCacheDataTable(pEntry);
    printf("stat = %d\n", stat);
    pEntry = pEntry->pNext;
    while (pEntry) {
        wprintf(L"%s : %d \n", (pEntry->pszName), (pEntry->wType));
        pEntry = pEntry->pNext;
    }
    free(pFirstEntry);
}
```

UPDATE: in fact you don't need to allocate any memory because DnsGetCacheDataTable allocated it itself. Tried to free the memory using DnsRecordListFree but it seems it doesn't work. Still leaks:

[image: Still leaks]

Finally I got the code that doesn't leak:

```
typedef int(WINAPI *DNS_GET_CACHE_DATA_TABLE)(PDNSCACHEENTRY*);

typedef void (WINAPI *P_DnsApiFree)(PVOID pData);

void UpdateDNS(void)
{
    PDNSCACHEENTRY pEntry = NULL;
    // Loading DLL
    HINSTANCE hLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("DNSAPI.dll"));
    // Get function address
    DNS_GET_CACHE_DATA_TABLE DnsGetCacheDataTable = (DNS_GET_CACHE_DATA_TABLE)GetProcAddress(hLib, "DnsGetCacheDataTable");
    P_DnsApiFree pDnsApiFree = (P_DnsApiFree)GetProcAddress(hLib, "DnsApiFree");
    int stat = DnsGetCacheDataTable(&pEntry);
    PVOID pFirstEntry = pEntry;
    printf("stat = %d\n", stat);
    pEntry = pEntry->pNext;
    while (pEntry) {
        wprintf(L"%s : %d \n", (pEntry->pszName), (pEntry->wType));
        pDnsApiFree(pEntry->pszName);
        PVOID p = pEntry;
        pEntry = pEntry->pNext;
        pDnsApiFree(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: @mazkopolo you're right, I've just updated the answer.

Comment: you need to free pFirstEntry. also, you can use DnsFree(ptr, DnsFreeFlat) instead of pDnsApiFree(ptr);

Answer (score 4):

There are several problems with this code.

Consider that you're calling `LoadLibrary` at the beginning without calling `FreeLibrary` at the end. Whilst not technically a memory leak, it's probably not the brightest idea...

Consider that by moving straight to `pEntry->pNext` *before* the loop, you're skipping an entry. Your memory leak occurs in that very same line of code, when you assign over the value returned by `malloc`:

```
PDNSCACHEENTRY pEntry = (PDNSCACHEENTRY) malloc(sizeof(DNSCACHEENTRY));
/* ... */
pEntry = pEntry->pNext;
```

You don't even need `malloc` for this, but to make matters worse, you should only ever `free` values that `malloc` returns, rendering this erroneous:

```
free(pEntry);
```

In fact, not only do you not need `malloc` (or `free`) for this, but what do you need is actually `DnsRecordListFree`.

Here's what your code should probably look like:

```
PDNS_RECORD entry;
HINSTANCE hLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("DNSAPI.dll"));
DNS_GET_CACHE_DATA_TABLE DnsGetCacheDataTable = (DNS_GET_CACHE_DATA_TABLE) GetProcAddress(hLib, "DnsGetCacheDataTable");
int stat = DnsGetCacheDataTable(&entry);
printf("stat = %d\n", stat);
for (DNSCACHEENTRY *pTemp = &entry; pTemp; pTemp = pTemp->pNext) {
    wprintf(L"%s : %d \n", pTemp->pszName, pTemp->wType);
}
DnsRecordListFree(entry, DnsFreeRecordList);
```

Comment: int stat = DnsGetCacheDataTable(pEntry); gives: "no suitable conversion function from "DNSCACHEENTRY" to "PVOID"" and DnsRecordListFree(entry, DnsFreeRecordList); gives "no suitable conversion function from "DNSCACHEENTRY" to "PDNSCACHEENTRY"" error.

Comment: it gives me " no suitable conversion function from "DNSCACHEENTRY" to "PVOID" exists" for last line (DnsRecordListFree(entry, DnsFreeRecordList);)

Comment: It seems "DnsGetCacheDataTable" only accepts ->PDNSCACHEENTRY not DNSCACHEENTRY.

Comment: @mazkopolo `PDNSCACHEENTRY` is `DNSCACHEENTRY *`... Can you tell me what the `*` means, and why they would add a `P` to denote it?

Comment: It gives me the following error when I use your last update: "Error 1 error C2664: 'int (PDNSCACHEENTRY *)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'DNSCACHEENTRY *' to 'PDNSCACHEENTRY *'"

Comment: Could you please compile it and see the error message?

Comment: My bad... Try that one ;)

Comment: I hadn't noticed that you were using the wrong type. If I were to omit the faulty example, then my response would still be the same: You should use `DnsRecordListFree`.